# AWS: Classic RDS to VPC resulted in high CPU

Tags: mysql, amazon-vpc, rds

We are running a **single 5.7 MySQL Database**
for couple of years using Amazon AWS RDS service.

3 days ago we moved our server from a Classic RDS into a VPC (no other action was done).
The load on our system is constant and mild, but since the move, we had several times where the **RDS database gets to 100% CPU** (for several minutes each time).

This block the entire system

Anyone have an idea what this could be?

===
Additional Info: Found out that since the move to VPC, our webservers often disconnected by the database/vpc. We have around 250 active connections
Any definition/limit increase we need to set in the VPC/database to keep the connection alive?

[Disconnect peer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5zMC.png)

[cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls5xj.png)

Comment: RDS databases in VPCs don't typically do that. Can you post some graphs from Cloudwatch showing various metrics - CPU, RAM usage, I/O, network, etc? You could also use the analysis tools and look at the logs. I'd also look at the client to see if there was unusual traffic being sent.

Comment: Ok, I did further check and saw that the connection between the webserver to the database is cut often. (see details added in the body of the original message)

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RDS type? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @MikoMeltzer  This URL may be helpful as a checkoff list for you to review VPC details.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html   Could you post any SSL configuration information?

Comment: Do you hae the slowlog turned on?  With what value of `long_query_time`?

Comment: Please give more details on your environment - instance size, graph of things like instance credits if it's a T type, the stats I requested above, etc.